# Floating drop down validation list Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have been looking to see if there is an option to create a floating drop-down validation list in Google sheets using Google scripts (not a simple drop-down validation list)

For example, when I click a cell A1, the drop-down list appears And when I select one of the values from the drop-down it should enter the selected value into the corresponding cell B1.

Comment: sounds to me like you need VLOOKUP

Comment: @player0 how to create a floating drop-down list in Google sheets

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: @player0 Please find the link below. In the drop-down list sheet , I have list of value to be used as drop down and in sheet 2, if i click on cell A1 it should pop up a floating drop-down with values from the drop-down list sheet . Once selected any value from the floating drop-down, the selected value should appear at B1 cell. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n5FBSQUR0AWX6smNqZ3ZmVrfIjVXOuBxOw2_PNrARjU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see, unfortunately, this kind of functionality is not possible in google sheets. dropdowns can be only pre-set